# TypeError: Cannot create property 'constant' on number '123' web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodejs

I am trying to send transaction to my contract via node js but I am encountering many problems.

This is my node js code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));

var myAddress = '0x4e5d87aB06D13a17E9f35dfC235B4fC70669151d';
var fs = require('fs'); 
var contractABI = fs.readFileSync('../abis/Marketplace.json')
var contractAddress = '0x15Cb1e185b0269fFd93516BE007B2aF4BA59f2F5';
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);

contract.methods.updateModifications("fileName","Changes were made", new Date()).call({from: myAddress});

console.log("Notified successfully");
```

This is my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Marketplace {
    uint public notificationCount = 0;
    mapping(uint => FileChanges) public modifications;
    struct FileChanges
    {
        string name;
        address madeBy;
        string changesMade;
        string timeStamp;
    }
    function updateModifications(string memory _name, string memory _message, string memory _date) onlyOwner public payable
    {
        notificationCount++;
        modifications[notificationCount] = FileChanges(_name, msg.sender, "Contract created", _date);
    }
}
```

And when I try to run my code, this is my error:

```
C:\Users\Vishnu.Siripuram\Desktop\project\marketplace\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\dist\web3-eth-contract.cjs.js:293
        abiItem.constant = _this.isConstant(abiItem);
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot create property 'constant' on number '123'
    at C:\Users\Vishnu.Siripuram\Desktop\project\marketplace\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\dist\web3-eth-contract.cjs.js:293:26
    at Buffer.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AbiMapper.map (C:\Users\Vishnu.Siripuram\Desktop\project\marketplace\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\dist\web3-eth-contract.cjs.js:292:11)
    at new AbstractContract (C:\Users\Vishnu.Siripuram\Desktop\project\marketplace\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\dist\web3-eth-contract.cjs.js:984:38)
    at ContractModuleFactory.createContract (C:\Users\Vishnu.Siripuram\Desktop\project\marketplace\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\dist\web3-eth-contract.cjs.js:1089:14)
    at new Eth._this.Contract (C:\Users\Vishnu.Siripuram\Desktop\project\marketplace\node_modules\web3-eth\dist\web3-eth.cjs.js:403:50)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Vishnu.Siripuram\Desktop\project\marketplace\src\components\notifier.js:17:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:945:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:32)
```

Comment: what is your web3 version? And why do you need parasedABI variable when you don't use it?

Comment: My web3 version is 1.2.4. And parsedABI i've forgot to remove here, already removed in my code. Now removed here also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, It was a very silly mistake now that I got it but was eating my head for 24 hours.

It is in this line:

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);
```

I missed the .abi after contractABI. So my JS compiler did not understand what it was looking at. Changing it to contractABI.abi worked just fine.

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI.abi,contractAddress);
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your update function is a payable function which mean you must send money to it. The call method doesn't support a way to send money so you must use send method with some eth for it to work: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send

Tldr: Use send with some value instead of call

Comment: That doesn't change the error I get but could've corrected a future error. 
It still has the same problem because the problem is with web3 for reading the ABI

Comment: @vteja711 have you try to wrap them up in an async function. like const func = async () => { // your code } and then run the async function. Something like in this video tutorial: https://youtu.be/4cPEGO4NAao

Comment: So, it was a very idiotic thing I did and that was ```var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);``` I missed .abi. LOL